# Same value other HEX entries in file

Tags: c#, c++, character-encoding

I'm running 2 programs that execute the same code : write to a binary file.

When the c++ code saves a one byte with value 2 to the file it seems to be binary stored as HEX 02.  However when my C# program writes it to the file it seems to be stored as HEX 32.

Could it be this has something to do with char encoding UTF_16 is default in C#? (if I read correctly in an article a few days ago.)

Any way to make sure C# will write the byte value 2 to file as HEX 02 instead of HEX 32 ?

```
            EndianBinaryWriter writer = new EndianBinaryWriter(new FileStream("myfile.dat", Endian.Little);
            char LineDepth = '4';
            if(MaxDev<=127) {
                LineDepth = '1';
            } else
            if(MaxDev<=32767) {
                LineDepth = '2';
            }

            // write line header
            //char BlockBuf[5];
            //MemoryStream BlockBuf = new MemoryStream();
            //EndianBinaryWriter BlockBufWriter = new EndianBinaryWriter(endian, BlockBuf);

            //hfzMemcpy(BlockBuf, &LineDepth, 1); // store line depth
            //hfzMemcpy(BlockBuf+1, &FirstVal, 4); // store first value (32bit precis)
            writer.Write(LineDepth);
```

This is a bit of an extract of the code but it should give the intention.  I like to write away exactly one byte with value 1, 2 or 4 depending on some if statement.  Now I always thought that a char was one byte so I'm trying to write it as a char but that seems to be wrong cause when I compare it with a file as how it SHOULD be it should  be HEX 02 while in my file it's HEX 32

## UPDATE

John showed me the light , by putting the byte value 2 from a source file into a char , I was not putting value 2 in that char but value 32 , which caused my resulting file to be corrupt.  Kind of a rookie mistake, but maybe my question will help out other rookies in the future ?

Comment: It's almost certainly to do with the code that you're using in both languages... but you haven't posted either piece of code. Then again, the fact that you're talking about a *binary* file but then talking about *chars* suggests that you should be thinking very carefully about whether this is really text or binary. C may be ambivalent about it: C# isn't.

Comment: Are you by chance writing the char '2' (as opposed to the integer value 2) to the file in c#? 32 is the ascii character code for '2'.

Comment: @Jon SKeet : I updated the question with an extract of the code

Comment: @Anderas: I like to write just one byte with the value 1 , 2 or 4 (in this case 2)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're writing the *character* '4', '1' or '2' - which is encoded in UTF-16 as 0x00 0x34 (etc).

It seems to me that you want to write a `short` or `ushort` value or 4, 1, or 2:

```
short lineDepth = 4;
if (MaxDev <= 127) {
    lineDepth = 1;
} else
if (MaxDev <= 32767) {
    lineDepth = 2;
}
writer.Write(lineDepth);
```

Note that's still writing two bytes. If you just want to write a *single* byte (your post and your comments seem to say different things), you want:

```
byte lineDepth = 4;
if (MaxDev <= 127) {
    lineDepth = 1;
} else
if (MaxDev <= 32767) {
    lineDepth = 2;
}
writer.Write(lineDepth);
```

It's *very* important that you understand the difference between 1 (an integer constant) and '1' (a character constant). You should try to avoid using text unless you're *really* trying to represent text.

Also note that "hex" is just one way of viewing the file. There's no such thing as a "hex entry" - there are just bytes. So the byte with a value of "sixteen" can be viewed as 16 (decimal) or 0x10 (hex). Those are two different ways of viewing the exact same content.

Comment: I'll give it a try see the result however I believed a short was 2 bytes, while I just want to write one byte, two bytes would probably ruin the file format.  I'll give the result shortly

Comment: @kenny: If you only want to write one byte, why does your question talk about: "Any way to make sure C# will write the 2 char to file"? See my edit for a one byte version... and please think about how you can make your questions clearer in future. I'll edit out the `short` part if the `byte` version turns out to be what you want.

Comment: Totally right I was totally confusing in my wording.  I'm actually a java developer and I'm getting lost in languages.  I totally forgot about the byte datatype.  I was forcing a byte I read in a source file into a char to make sure I had one byte and then writing that character, completely forgetting that I don't actually still have value 2 as byte but value 32.  Updated my question to make it more clearly